# Como receber alterações de feed instantaneamente?

Tags: android, web-service, xml, feed

Estou tentando fazer um player de podcast e tenho uma dúvida a respeito do sistema de feed.

Eu pensei em fazer um botão de sincronização, que seria capaz de retornar a lista atualizada de podcasts quando pressionado. Mas acho que seria interessante se o usuário pudesse receber notificações a respeito de novos episódios lançados.

Existe alguma maneira de programar para receber automaticamente alterações de feed no dispositivo, sem que haja a necessidade de ficar consultando periodicamente o xml de feed?

Comment: Talvez você possar push notification